# Как определить соприкосновение круглых объектов?

Tags: python, tkinter

Создаю игру на python, с помощью модуля tkinter. Мне нужно определить, прикасается ли круглое изображение звезды с игроком. Я знаю, что существует функция **find_overlapping,** но она определяет прикосновение в зоне квадрата.

Вот так определяет сейчас:
[image]

А нужно, чтобы  определяло так:
[image]

Comment: Через find_overlapping определять соприкосновение, а потом проверять расстояние между центрами (если оно меньше чем сумма радиусов, то соприкосновение есть)

Comment: Какая фигура у игрока?